# How to remove author initials, but not globally?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using `Biblatex`. I want to cite "According to Jones, Smith and Green 2008...". Because I have two authors with the surname Green in my bibliography, I instead get: "According to Jones, Smith and H. G. Green...".

I do not want to add `uniquename=false` to my biblatex options, because I have other (single) authors elsewhere who need disambiguating. However, there is no ambiguity in the citations with multiple authors.

How do I define a `\citeauthorwithoutinitials` command? I've found several examples of custom commands, but not documentation for how to construct my own.

Comment: Have you tried `uniquename=mininit`? Or you can also set `uniquename` per-entry with `OPTIONS={uniquename=false}`.

Comment: You could also try `uniquename=minfull` instead of `uniquename=mininit` (don't use the former if you have `giveninits=true` set, it will fall back to the latter automatically with a warning anyway). If you need more specific [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) would really help us to investigate further and give an answer that we know works for you.

Comment: It looks like uniquename=mininit works. It's done some interesting things to the single authors - who gets initials and who gets full names seems to have changed - but it's not important enough to try and produce a MWE at this point.
I would still be interested in the documentation for custom citation commands, though.

Comment: AFAIK `uniquename=mininit` will not let anyone gave full names. If you want to allow for full names, go with `uniquename=minfull`. What documentation do you expect for custom citation commands?

Comment: @PLK Do you want to type up a quick answer here, please?

Answer (score 3):

`uniquename=mininit` or `uniquename=minfull` do what you need. These options only disambiguate names where the list of names in which they occur is ambiguous. This prevents the name disambiguation system in `biber` from disambiguating family names wherever they occur, which is not what you want.